# Need to verify inner join vs subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written an inner join equivalent of subquery. Could someone let me know if it is correct way of doing things and if it is more efficient way. Does the the ON keyword filter the same way as where clause

**Subquery**

```
select 
        companyId,
        fiscalYear,
        fiscalQuarter,
        periodenddate
    into #PeriodTbl
    from(   
        select
            fp.companyId,
            fp.fiscalYear,
            fp.fiscalQuarter,
            fi.periodenddate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fp.companyId, fp.fiscalYear, fp.fiscalQuarter ORDER BY fi.periodEndDate DESC) rowno
        from ciqfinperiod fp 
            join ciqfininstance fi on fi.financialperiodid = fp.financialperiodid
        where fp.periodtypeid = 4
            and fi.periodenddate > @date
            and fi.latestforfinancialperiodflag = 1
            and latestfilingforinstanceflag = 1 
            and fp.companyId in (select id from #companyId)

        ) a
    where a.rowno = 1
```

**inner join**

```
select 
        companyId,
        fiscalYear,
        fiscalQuarter,
        periodenddate
    into #PeriodTbl
    from(   
        select
            fp.companyId,
            fp.fiscalYear,
            fp.fiscalQuarter,
            fi.periodenddate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fp.companyId, fp.fiscalYear, fp.fiscalQuarter ORDER BY fi.periodEndDate DESC) rowno
        from ciqfinperiod fp inner join #companyId ci on fp.companyId = ci.id
            join ciqfininstance fi on fi.financialperiodid = fp.financialperiodid
        where fp.periodtypeid = 4
            and fi.periodenddate > @date
            and fi.latestforfinancialperiodflag = 1
            and latestfilingforinstanceflag = 1 
            --and fp.companyId in (select id from #companyId)

        ) a
    where a.rowno = 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, an `INNER JOIN` and `IN` with subquery are not exactly the same.  The problem is that the `INNER JOIN` can introduce duplicate rows.

In your case, this seems unlikely because you are selecting ids.

Ironically, even if `#companyId` does have duplicates, then it won't make a difference (except in terms of performance).  That is because you are selecting only one row per company.

So, switching to an `INNER JOIN` seems fine.